# How to add external data as new columns in Power Query?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Today is my first day to use PowerBI 2.0 Desktop.

Is there any way to add new columns from external data into the existing table in my PowerBI?
Or is there anyway to add new columns from another table in PowerBI?

It seems that, in PowerQuery, all the tabs `Add Custom Column`, `Add Index Column` and `Duplicate Column` are all using the existing columns in the same table.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Merge Queries to join together two queries, which will let you bring in the other table's columns.

Also, Add Custom Column accepts an arbitrary expression, so you can reference other tables in that expression. For example, if Table1 and Table2 had the same number of rows, I could copy over Table2's column by doing the following:

1. Add an Index Column. Let's call it Index.
2. Add a Custom Column with the following expression: `Table2[ColumnName]{[Index]}`

Comment: Thank you very much Alejandro!